# does anyone know what's wrong? it's a simple script

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

I was developing a script for trading when these errors came up:

Script could not be translated from: |B|up:= close[1] >

Script could not be translated from: |B|dn:= close[1] <

Script could not be translated from: |B|trend := nz(trend[1]

Script could not be translated from: |B|trend := trend == -1

is referring to this part of the script:

```
atr= changeATR ? atr(Periods) : atr2
up=src2-(Multiplier*atr)
up1= nz(up[1],up)
up:= close[1] > up1 ? max(up,up1) : up
dn=src2+(Multiplier*atr)
dn1= nz(dn[1], dn)
dn:= close[1] < dn1 ? min(dn, dn1) : dn
trend = 1
trend := nz(trend[1], trend)
trend := trend == -1 and close > dn1 ? 1 : trend == 1 and close < up1 ? -1: trend
```

do you know what i did wrong? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your script is probably missing the version header and check that you have either study() or strategy()

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
```